# How do I test the perceived quality of my SAAS product?

Tags: user-research, surveys

I have a question about how to evaluate our B2B product; we want to understand what would be the best way to assess the quality perceived by those who are using the product on a daily basis. The most common instruments in the B2B market are the NPS and CSAT (but they are very targeted to the buyer, not the user). What other methods might we try?

Comment: We want to know if our platform solves their day-to-day life, when they use our platform, dashboard, service data, reports, and if the 'interface' part is very intuitive.

Note: There are many users on our platform, but the person who uses the platform is not the same person who hires our services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The SUS](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html) seems very well-suited to your needs, and this is indeed its main goal. [It's a standard and widely used method](https://measuringu.com/sus/).

> The System Usability Scale (SUS) provides a “quick and dirty”,
> reliable tool for measuring the usability.   It consists of a 10 item
> questionnaire with five response options for respondents; from
> Strongly agree to Strongly disagree.  Originally created by John
> Brooke in 1986, it allows you to evaluate a wide variety of products
> and services, including hardware, software, mobile devices, websites
> and applications.

Comment: Tks very much Vitaly!